# Replacements for UserAgentUtils

Tags: java, browser, operating-system, user-agent

Now that UserAgentUtils is end of life (http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils), what are good replacements for parsing useragents in Java that others have found?  Looking for all options here, paid and not.  Accuracy is key so I'm not looking to parse it myself unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 2):

What about [this lib](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-java)

It seems quite simple to use

```
String uaString = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3";
Parser uaParser = new Parser();
Client c = uaParser.parse(uaString);
System.out.println(c.userAgent.family);
// => "Mobile Safari"    
System.out.println(c.userAgent.major);
// => "5"    
System.out.println(c.userAgent.minor);
// => "1"    
System.out.println(c.os.family);
// => "iOS"     
System.out.println(c.os.major);
// => "5"
System.out.println(c.os.minor);
// => "1"
System.out.println(c.device.family);
// => "iPhone
```

Comment: does it work with maven?

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.moilioncircle</groupId>
   <artifactId>user-agent-utils</artifactId>
   <version>1.53</version>
</dependency>
```

No need to change any code.